# Default to IPv6 Linux

Tags: linux, ip, ipv6

I have IPv6 setup on Linux however it is not using IPv6 by default unless I specify it.  For example:

```
ssh -v HOSTNAME
```

I see ssh connecting to the IPv4 address.  The only way I can get it to use IPv6 is if I:

```
ssh -6 HOSTNAME
-or-
ssh IP::v6%INTERFACE
```

I use the same exact host on a Solaris box and IPv6 works fine.

Solaris:

```
nslookup host1
Server:         10.1.44.100
Address:        10.1.44.100#53

Name:   host1.sc.somehost.net
Address: 10.1.42.37

dig AAAA host1.sc.somehost.net

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R8 <<>> AAAA host1.sc.somehost.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4583
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 5, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;host1.sc.somehost.net.      IN      AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
host1.sc.somehost.net. 3600  IN      AAAA    2600:REST_OF_PREFIX:2::37
```

On Linux the output is the exact same.

There is no /etc/gai.conf on my Linux host.  On my solaris host I do have the following in my /etc/nsswitch.conf (which I was told "turns on" ipv6 by default.

```
 ipnodes:    files dns
```

Just for kicks my IPv6 linux config is as follows:

```
 bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr NOPE 
      inet addr:10.1.44.194  Bcast:10.1.45.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: 2600:REST_OF_PREFIX:1::44:194/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2600:REST_OF_PREFIX:AUTOCONFIG_MAC_ADDR_ADDRESS/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::NOT_GETTIN_MY_MAC/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1197675 errors:0 dropped:569214 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:878545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:447693586 (426.9 MiB)  TX bytes:793250645 (756.5 MiB)
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: It's probably related to DNS - do an nslookup on HOSTNAME and tell us what comes back. Do the same thing for the Solaris box so we can see the differences in behavior.

Comment: Using IPv6 _is_ the default. In addition to posting a host lookup for the address, please also post the contents of `/etc/gai.conf`.

Comment: You say linux but you don't say which distribution. Might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry.  It's Oracle Linux (Basically RHEL6)

Answer (score 1):

There are (older, I hoped) versions of Linux in which RFC1918 IPv4 address space is preferred over IPv6. See for example [debian bug #428434 libc6: Resolver prefers IPv4 to IPv6 in some cases](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=428434). You probably don't have a /etc/gai.conf file to fix this, this only came in newer versions.

Comment: The bug says this was fixed in glibc 2.5. RHEL 6 has glibc 2.12.